# Not having to pass entire row to create a new column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following function to calculation a movie resolution from a movie title:

```
def new__resolution(row):
    resolution = row['resolution']
    if resolution == '4k/UHD': resolution = 'UHD'
    if resolution not in ('SD', 'HD', 'UHD'): resolution = None
    if '_HD_' in row['file_name']: resolution = 'HD'
    if '_SD_' in row['file_name']: resolution = 'SD'
    return resolution
```

And I create the new column like this:

```
df['new__resolution'] = df.apply(new__resolution, axis=1)
```

My question is this seems like a heavy-handed way to create a new column passing the entire row. Is there a better way, such as just passing the column itself? Something like:

```
df['new__resolution'] = df['resolution'].apply(new__resolution)
```

And the first two lines of the function would be:

```
def new__resolution(value):
    resolution = value
```

How would this be done when passing a single column instead of the entire row?

---

**Update:** actually, now that I review the question, I cannot just pass a single column, as it depends on two fields not just one (resolution, file_name). Given that, is there a way to just pass two columns, or am I better off just passing the entire row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your function to

```
def new__resolution(row):
    resolution = row
    if resolution == '4k/UHD': resolution = 'UHD'
    if resolution not in ('SD', 'HD', 'UHD'): resolution = None
    if '_HD_' in row['file_name']: resolution = 'HD'
    if '_SD_' in row['file_name']: resolution = 'SD'
    return resolution

df['new__resolution'] = df['resolution'].map(new__resolution)
```

---

If two columns

```
df['new__resolution'] = df[['col1','col2']].apply(new__resolution, axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks, could you please add a bit of more elaboration on the two functions and what you're doing here? Mainly the difference between the `map` and `apply`. Also, what would the function signature look like for the second one? Is it accepting a row still and the row passed just have those two columns?

Comment: @David542 when do map for series , it is same as apply , but for dataframe , we need apply. Since you pull out the row , so we try to reduce the unnecessary columns as many as we can to speed it up.

Comment: I see. I understand the second one now. Still a bit fuzzy on the `map` vs `apply` though. Also, which of the above two would you suggest?

Comment: @David542 I will do apply, but map is good for the index , apply is not, you can do df.index.map() not df.index.apply

Comment: thanks, using the second way returned in about half the time of the first one.

Comment: @David542 that is what we would like to see ~